# Setting variable variables inside a foreach

Tags: php, loops, foreach

I am trying to use $value inside the $feed_title variable. And generate all 200 $feed_title variables.

What I am trying to accomplish would look like this:

**Feed Url**: http://something.com/term/###/feed
**Feed Title**: Some Title

Where the ### varies from 100-300.

I am using the following code, and getting the urls, but not sure how to get the titles for each feed:

```
$arr = range(100,300); 

foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
{ 
    unset($arr[$key + 1]);

    $feed_title = simplexml_load_file('http://www.something.com/term/'
     . ??? . '/0/feed');

    echo 'Feed URL: <a href="http://www.something.com/term/' . $value 
     . '/0/feed">http://www.something.com//term/' . $value 
     . '/0/feed</a><br/>  Feed Category: ' . $feed_title->channel[0]->title
     . '<br/>';
}
```

Do I need another loop inside of the foreach? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is not clear. What are you still trying to do with the given URI?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, I am trying to use $value inside the $feed_title variable. And generate all 200 $feed_title variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the title of a page, use this function:

```
    function getTitle($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}
```

Here's some sample code:

```
<?php
function getTitle($Url){
    $str = file_get_contents($Url);
    if(strlen($str)>0){
        preg_match("/\<title\>(.*)\<\/title\>/",$str,$title);
        return $title[1];
    }
}

$arr = range(300,305); 
foreach($arr as $value) 
{ 

    $feed_title = getTitle('http://www.translate.com/portuguese/feed/' . $value);

    echo 'Feed URL: <a href="http://www.translate.com/portuguese/feed/' . $value . '">http://www.translate.com/portuguese/feed/' . $value . '</a><br/>
          Feed Category: ' . $feed_title . '<br/>';


}
?>
```

This gets the title from translate.com pages. I just limited the number of pages for faster execution.

Just change the getTitle to your function if you want to get the title from xml.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array created with range, use a for loop as follows:

```
for($i = 100; $i <= 300; $i++){
     $feed = simplexml_load_file('http://www.something.com/term/' . $i . '/0/feed');
     echo 'Feed URL: <a href="http://something.com/term/' . $i . '/0/feed">http://www.something.com/term/' . $i . '/0/feed/</a> <br /> Feed category: ' . $feed->channel[0]->title . '<br/>';
}
```